# Using IPv4 address for Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, ipv4

Why use an IPv4 address for Tomcat? I want to learn why it is used to access our application? Why can't I access without IPV4 address in oracle package?

Comment: you can access Tomcat in different ways like with IPv4 with port, without port via domain etc. You provided information doesn't describe what is your question exactly. Please provide more information

Comment: Hi Ghayel.Why we need to ip number in our local project?

Comment: Surely Tomcat is accessed over HTTP, which is layered on top of TCP, and TCP sends/receives IP packets which need an IP address so the packets can be sent to the correct host - you don't get around that even if your tomcat server is running on your local machine. (albeit in that case you can use the localhost IP address, 127.0.0.1)